# Erro no Spring Framework: Não foi possível localizar nem carregar a classe principal

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

Estou seguindo algumas aulas de um workshop de Spring, mas não consigo prosseguir por conta do erro: **Não foi possível localizar nem carregar a classe principal.** Segue abaixo o código que contém a função main:

```
package com.algaworks.vinhos;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class OficinaSpringFrameworkApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(OficinaSpringFrameworkApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

Segue abaixo a estrutura de pastas:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Como vc está executando o projeto? Pelo Maven? Gradle? IDE? Onde está sendo exibido este erro?

Comment: Eu estou executando o projeto pelo Spring Tool Suite, o erro é exibido no console da IDE. Antes de compilar uma mensagem é exibida alertando que o projeto possui erros.

Comment: Você pode incluir a estrutura de pastas do seu projeto?

Comment: Estrutura de pastas adicionadas no post

Answer (score 1):

Essa mensagem no STS poderá ser problema de repositório do Maven.
Já me aconteceu um projeto que estava a funcionar, deixar de funcionar e começar a dar esse erro após baixar outras libraries para outro projeto.
Fazer o Maven - Update Projet e esperar até ao fim do STS atualizar, poderá resolver o problema.

Answer (score -2):

Olá, estava com esse problema, coloquei a pasta do meu projeto no disco "C".
Acredito que seja um problema de visibilidade do Maven e Spring.

[Esse arquivo demo é um teste de projeto, nesse diretório rodou tranquilamente](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SU5QS.png)